# PyCharm 2020.2 can't open terminal

Tags: python, python-3, terminal, ide

I am having a problem with PyCharm on my raspberry pi. Everything works just fine when using PyCharm 2020.2, except for its terminal.
When I try to open the terminal tab it says the following:

```
Cannot open Local Terminal
```

Then a long line which I can't copy or fully see that starts with "Failed to open [<place in files which I can't fully see>]"

```
See your idea.log (Help | Show Log in File Manager) for the details.
```

If someone knows how to solve this, it would really help me out.

Comment: Try checking IDE Settings, then Tools -> Terminal -> Start directory path. It must exist.

Comment: Thanks, I found it! What file do I have to choose there in order for the terminal to work?

Comment: Sorry to add another answer, but commenting does not work for me.
Normally you will prefer your project directory in this setting part mentioned above.

Comment: There is a terminal section in the settings, it has "choose directory" with which you can choose what to use as your terminal. What it has automatically chosen doesn't work for some reason.